# Programmatically loading images in Android

Tags: android, image, loading, device

I would like to load images from my Drawable Resource folders without explicitly typing the identifiers for them. For example : Loading the images in drawable-mdpi using a 'for' loop and using the integer as an argument for the Bitmap Decoder. Which seems to work in theory, but my concern is: is the integer 0x7F020000 where drawable Int ID's seem to begin constant across all devices? or if I create code to load images this way will it not work on a different Android device than the one I am testing on?

Is there a better way to achieve what I have described?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I know I can load images the way I want. The real question is : Will the ID Int 0x7F020000 BE CONSTANT ACROSS ALL DEVICES. Since I will use this as the base 'Int' to Address my images Ex. 0x7F020000 + 3 = Image Number 3. Since Images begin at 0x7F020000. Will the code work across all devices? Because I have no other device to test with

Comment: at the very least every time you compile an new apk this address is susceptible to change

Comment: the id's are changing when compiling if you add more res files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not hard-code the id even you can get it from R file. From android [API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html):

```
Although the R class is where resource IDs are specified, you should never need to look there to discover a resource ID.
```

[R class](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html) will change its content when you update your resource, and clean and [rebuilt](http://knowledgefolders.com/akc/display?url=DisplayNoteIMPURL&reportId=2883&ownerUserId=satya). It means you cannot make sure the same name of resource will be assigned the same value **after each built**. However, IDs will **be the same (not change) after apk released and installed** in different devices.

Simple solution:

1. Create your images and name them sequentially like: `img0.png`, `img1.png`, ... and place them in `drawable` folder.
2. Get image id from its name by:

   `int imgID = getResources().getIdentifier("img00" , "drawable", getPackageName());`

So if you want to use `for` loop, it should be something like:

```
for(int i=0; i < total_image_number; i++) {
    int imgID = getResources().getIdentifier("img"+i , "drawable", getPackageName());
    //do something else with our imgID here
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting something relevant and useful. Although, this answer suggests not Hard-coding the id, It doesn't answer as to if the base address for ID's drawables will change across devices.

Comment: Cheers. Please check it as correct answer if it address your question. :)